# Apply/Call with constructor

Tags: javascript

Is this the appropriate way to use apply and call with a constructor (providing an empty object)?

```
var findCats = RegExp.apply({}, ["cats?", "ig"]);
var findDogs = RegExp.call({}, "dogs?", "ig");
```

I just have a sneaking suspicion that under the covers:

```
function Foo(a,b,c) { this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; }
var foo = Foo.call({}, "a", "b", "c");
```

is not going to do quite the same thing as

```
var foo = new Foo("a", "b", "c");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Using call/apply directly with a constructor isn't the same.

You could modify the constructor though to test of the object being used is an instance of the constructor...

```
function Foo(a,b,c) { 
    if( !(this instanceof Foo) )
        return new Foo(a,b,c)
    this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; 
}

var findCats = Foo.apply({}, ["a", "b", "c"]);
```

So from within the constructor, if `this` is not `instanceof Foo`, it calls `new Foo(a,b,c)` passing on the arguments.

This of course will not work if an unknown number of arguments is to be passed.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ss3m/

---

A different option would be to have a zero argument behavior for the constructor that just returns the new object from `Foo`, then do the `.apply()` as a separate call.

```
function Foo(a,b,c) { 
    if( arguments.length === 0 )
        return this;
    this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; 
}

var findCats = new Foo; // get the empty Foo object

Foo.apply(findCats, ["a", "b", "c"]); // apply the args separately
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ss3m/1/

Comment: the instanceof check is just code bloat. constructors should be called with `new`

Comment: @Raynos: What do you have against bloat? Without bloat, jQuery wouldn't be possible! ;)

Comment: ... We don't need that kind of nonsense, either allow your API to work with `new` or without new. Both is bad API design (yes jQuery has bad API design)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same thing, native constructors usually have a lot of magic in them so even passing null there works.

But with custom constructors:

`var foo = Foo.call({}, "a", "b", "c");`

`Foo` is called as a normal function and therefore `foo` will be `undefined` because `Foo` doesn't return anything when called as a normal function. Even if you added `return this` there, `foo` would not have the proto link to `Foo.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var foo = new Foo("a", "b", "c");
```

is almost the same as:

```
var foo = (function() { var obj = {}; Foo.call(obj, "a", "b", "c"); return obj; })();
```

but not exactly because of some bookkeeping.

Comment: The `obj = Object.create(Foo.prototype)` step is really, really important

Comment: @Raynos yes that's what I meant by the "bookkeeping" note :-)  I understood (perhaps inaccurately) the focus of the question to be about the basic *value* of the right-hand side of those assignments, so that's what I tried to address.

Answer (score 0):

`var foo = new Foo("a", "b", "c");`

Could be written as

`var foo = new(Foo, "a", "b", "c");`

Which means you would implement `new` as

```
function new(constructor) {
    var o = Object.create(constructor.prototype);
    var ret = o.constructor.call(o, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    if (typeof ret !== "number" && 
        typeof ret !== "string" &&
        typeof ret !== "boolean" &&
        ret !== undefined &&
        ret !== null
    ) {
        return ret;
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: You're not suggesting that the function actually be named `new`, right?

Comment: No, I think `new` actually throws errors in older browsers as a function name

Comment: Not just older browsers. It's a reserved word. You're probably thinking of property names. Reserved words are valid there, but older browsers will break.

Comment: Ah your right, `function new() {}` is invalid because new is not allowed to be a function name identifier